# How to convert a decimal value to int using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there an Ampscript function that we could use to convert a decimal value to integer?

if not, is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use `FormatNumber(1,2,3)` and set the precision to 0. Note that this will round the value.

```
Set @IntegerValue = FormatNumber(@YourDecimal, "F0")
```

For additional information and examples check out the documentation: [FormatNumber](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/formatnumber/)

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are looking for the [FormatNumber function()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm)

> **FormatNumber(value, formatType, cultureCode**
>
> value (string) Value to receive specified formatting
>
> Valid format type value:
>
> - **C** - Currency
> - **D** - Decimal
> - **E** - Exponential
> - **F** - Fixed
>     point
> - **G** - General
> - **N** - Number
> - **P** -
>     Percent
> - **R** - Round-trip
> - **X** - Hexadecimal
> - You can optionally follow
>     this code with a number to indicate the precision of the number. For
>     example, a currency value with a precision of 2 uses the
>     parameter**C2**.
>
> cultureCode (string) Culture code used to indicate the correct date format

I would do the following:

```
%%=FormatNumber('1234.567','F0','en-US')=%%
```

This will make your number round up though, and not display the raw number without the decimals. Output would be: **1235**

If you need to remove just the decimals with no rounding, you will need to do a substring and indexof().

```
%%[

SET @YourNumber = "123.23"
SET @Index = Indexof(@YourNumber, '.')
SET @Integer = Substring(@YourNumber, "1", Subtract(@Index, 1))

]%%
```

You then Output your variable:  `%%=v(@Integer)=%%` which would output: **123**

*You need to subtract one in the substring off the index to remove the decimal place.