# Extra decimal is showing in my Point_Balance data point in my email should be, e.g. Point_Balance = 567 instead of 567.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, contactbuilder

How to remove ".0" in data point that reflects in emails from Journey Builder that uses Contact Object from Salesforce to inject customers in the Journey. The proper value should be, e.g. **567** instead of **567.0**.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add some ampscript to format the value in your email.

You can use [Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm) or [FormatNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm). The functions will apply rounding.

```
%%[
    SET @num = 543.923123
    SET @num2 = 543.0
]%%
%%=Format(@num,"#")=%% 
<br>%%=FormatNumber(@num,"N0")=%%
<br>%%=Format(@num2,"#")=%% 
<br>%%=FormatNumber(@num2,"N0")=%%
```

Output will be:

544
544
543
543

If you know it will always be ".0" then you are fine. If not and you do not want rounding then you can use [SubString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm) instead.

```
%%[
    SET @num = 543.923123
]%%
%%=Substring(@num,1,Subtract(IndexOf(@num,'.'),1))=%%
```

Output:
543

Comment: Hi Josh, I went with your second option works well. Am not taking the risk of rounding customer's point balance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I'm following your question, but it sounds like you're trying to format a decimal figure as an integer within an email. If that's the case (in which case the source of the data is irrelevant), that's answered here: [How to convert a decimal value to int using ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172141/how-to-convert-a-decimal-value-to-int-using-ampscript)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in this known issue: [Journey Builder - Email Send Activity will append ".0" to whole number values specified in Decimal type Attribute](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCXGQA2&title=journey-builder-email-send-activity-will-append-0-to-whole-number-values-specified-in-decimal-type-attribute)

> Workaround
> 1 - Do not use a Decimal Type field -> this option may be difficult to implement after the fact.
>
> 2 - Utilize the Format() AMPScript function (or equivalent) to manipulate the value such that the ".0" is not included in the output.
>
> For workaround 2, using the earlier example:
>
> Original email content =
>
> %%progressVal%%
>
> Workaround email content=
>
> %%=Format(@progressVal,"#")=%%